# pino-pretty logging special characters as literal

Tags: node.js, logging, pinojs

I am using pino for logging, and using pino-pretty as well.
I have come across an issues with pino printing special characters.
ex:

```
key: "someKeyJson"
value: "\t\t\t\tsomeValueJson\nstring\t\tthat isnt being formatted"
```

When what I would like is something along the lines of\

```
key: "someKeyJson"
value: " someValueJson
string that isnt being formatted"
```

My first attempt was strictly replacing the values in the string being logged
`value.replace(/\t/g, ' ').replace(/\n/g, '\n')`
Which works fine for the tabs, however it still results in the log looking somethng like

```
key: "someKeyJson"
value: "someValueJson\nstring that isnt being formatted"
```

My other replacement attempts include:
`value.replace(/\t/g, ' ').replace(/\\n/g, '\n')`
`value.replace(/[\t]+/g, ' ').replace(/[\n]+/g, '\n')`

All of this resulting in the same output, which made me conclude perhaps there is either configuration needed, or it has something to do with either **ndjson** or **pino** itself
My configuration is as follows

```
const pinoLogger = pino({
    name: logger,
    level: LogLevel.DEBUG,
    transport: {
        target: 'pino-pretty',
        options: {
            destination: 1,
            colorize: true,
            translationTime: "SYS:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss.l"
}
```

Any help is appreciated as I havent seen much in the pino or pino-pretty docs, so if I missed anything that would also be helpful

Answer (score 1):

So I had forgotten to mention exactly how I am dong the logging
An example of a log in my application looked as follows

```
logger.info({key1, key2})
```

This would result with any special characters being printed out as the literal character represenataion, rather than an actual tab or newline.

I found if I formatted my json just as a string and printed the string, I was able to get my desired effect.

Ex:

```
formatLoggingString(logJson: any): string {
     let res = ''
     for (let key in logJson) {
          res += `${key}: ${logJson[key].replace(/[\t]{1}/g, ' ').replace(/\\n/g, '\n')}\n`
     }
     return res
}
```

Which would result in the log looking like what I want, so it seemed to be a problem with simly passing the json object directly to the pino logger. 
**Note**
It seemed to be passing an object and not a string that was the issue because doing something like

```
logger.info({key1, key2: keyValue.replace(...replace logic)})
```

Would not work either